# Apache Camel: two Ignite component in the same jvm

Tags: apache-camel, ignite

In Ignite component , I saw that there is not statement to get the current ignite cluster instance.

I have two separate camelContext and I used ignite component in both of them. But when it starts , it gives IgniteException normally. The error comes from this line:

```
org.apache.camel.component.ignite.IgniteComponent.doStart() : line 168 for Camel 2.17.0
```

So I am expecting to have an option for using existing cluster or create a new one in order to run two Ignite Instance in one JVM instance.

Am I missing something or is it like that?

Thx

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: It says that ignite has already been started. The exception is exactly the same if you try to Run Ignition.ignite()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start two Ignite nodes within one process you need to give them different names via `IgniteConfiguration.setGridName()` property. By default they both use 'null' and therefore the exception fails. Please try to set different names and see if it helps.